# Caliburn 2.0.0 and WP 8.1 : ActionMessage don't found target method

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

I've a problem with caliburn ActionMessage and windows phone 8.1 . Here my code:

```
       <ListBox x:Name="Categories" Grid.Row="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TileListBoxItemStyle}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button>
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                            <micro:ActionMessage MethodName="GoToPage">
                                <micro:Parameter Value="{Binding Path=PageId}" />
                            </micro:ActionMessage>
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PageDescription}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

On my app, the buttons will be created at runtime. But when I press button, I have this error:

**System.Exception: No target found for method GoToPage.
   at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.Invoke(Object eventArgs)
   at Caliburn.Micro.TriggerAction`1.Execute(Object sender, Object parameter)
   at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.Interaction.ExecuteActions(Object sender, ActionCollection actions, Object parameter)
   at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior.OnEvent(Object sender, Object eventArgs)**

Why? With WP 8.0 this code works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `AssociatedObject` on the ActionMessage. In your case this is the button.

Following issue describes the details:
https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/24

Comment: Hi tibel, thanks for answer. With AssociatedObject on ActionMessage I have this errors on build: 1- "The member "AssociatedObject" is not recognized or is not accesible." and 2- "The property 'AssociatedObject' was not found in type 'ActionMessage'" .

Comment: Hi tibel! Your solutions works! The error described in my previous comment depends from visual studio I think, now all my code build without any problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another reason of this exception may be.

Exception that @Max has described, also occures if you did not register your viewmodel:

```
_container = new WinRTContainer();
_container.RegisterWinRTServices();
_container.PerRequest<TestViewModel>(); // <-- without that line I got the same error
```

PS: Valid for Caliburn.Micro v.2.0.1